# how to subscribe to two eventDispatcher in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a large application and basically debugging a functionality. This functionality suppose to update the table and allow customer to sort the table based on the amount. Now all the CRUD operations on table are working fine but the problem is after adding data customer cant sort the table with new data based on the amount ( i.e customer can sort the data based on amount without newly added data )

to sort the problem i need to update the table as soon as new data added to the table and for that i somehow want following two events to work after one another

```
this.options.eventDispatcher.subscribe(TransactionEvent.TRANSACTION_ADD_COMPLETE, function(ev, data) {
                    obj.completeAdd(data);
                });
```

and

```
this.options.eventDispatcher.subscribe(TransactionEvent.REFRESH_DATA, function(ev, data) {
                    obj.loadMoneyOutData('reloadMoneyOutTables');
                });
```

how can i do that?

Any help/ suggestion is welcome and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps call your sort function from within one or both of your anon functions

Comment: @Josep  you can focus on just eventDispathcher and how to combine both events

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is necessary to keep the two events. If both functions are supposed to be triggered one after another you can use the first event and chain the functions inside it.

Comment: @if possible can you show me how to do that? i was looking for an example online but couldnt find one.

Comment: this.options.eventDispatcher.subscribe(TransactionEvent.TRANSACTION_ADD_COMPLETE, function(ev, data) {
                    obj.completeAdd(data);
                    obj.loadMoneyOutData('reloadMoneyOutTables');
                });

Comment: i tried that but i didnt work. we are dealing with two different events here which we have to subscribe. i dont know how to combine  two different event subscription in one